# Understanding phase noise specification in signal analyzer

Tags: noise, phase, spectrum-analyzer

I'm reading [this datasheet](http://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/5992-1822EN.pdf?id=2792918) and I see that phase noise is specified (page 12) in dBc/Hz for several offsets.

I understand that that "Hz" in the unit means that the value is specified normalized to a 1 Hz RBW. How do I find my phase noise for other RBW? Is it just scaling the value in the datasheet by the appropiate frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making some calculations and comparing my answer with some examples, I've found that the conversion is

PN_RBW = 10 log(RBW) + PN_1Hz

where PN_RBW is the desired phase noise (at the desired RBW (in Hertz)), expressed in dBc; and PN_1Hz is the phase noise normalized to 1 Hz as it appears in the datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously, since the phase noise power density isn't constant over frequency (otherwise, all the offsets would have the same dBc/Hz value!), no, it's not that easy.

You'll need to interpolate. Whether or not just using the noise density of the "closest" specified offset is sufficient depends on your bandwidth, the distance from the intended carrier and your accuracy needs.

Comment: I believe that you mean to interpolate between the values shown for the different frequencies in the "offset" column. But my question is how to obtain the according phase noise for a different RBW, not a different offset.

Comment: Well, integrate noise power density over frequency, and you get noise power.

Answer (score 0):

Phase noise is noise, so adds as power.

If one noise bandwidth is 10x that of another, and if the noise is uniform across the bandwidth, then the power in the first will be 10dB more than the other. To turn power into dB, we use 10xlog10(power).

As filter bandwidths are usually small compared to the slope on phase noise, we usually make the 'flat noise' assumption.

Scaling factors for a few bandwidths are as follows

```
bandwidth    dB(Hz)
   10Hz       +10
   30Hz       +15
  100Hz       +20
  30kHz       +45
   1MHz       +60
```

Note I've used the phrase 'noise bandwidth', and not RBW or resolution bandwidth. Although these are usually similar, they are not identical. Spectrum analysers specify their filters in terms of RBW, which is the width between -3dB(peak) points. The 'noise bandwidth' of a filter is that bandwidth of a filter which, if it had a rectangular shape, would read the same under noise conditions. The ratio of noise bandwidth to RBW varies with the shape of the filter. Modern spectrum analysers, especially ones which provide a dBc/Hz marker function, will also calibrate their filters for noise bandwidth, and use the appropriate measure for the marker.